# Best design for a floating view that will follow a tableview's center cell, instagram video search table

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to implement a view that will contains details about a table view cell. This view will be floating right above the center cell of a table view and should automatically re-assign itself to a new center-cell upon scrolling of the table.

My current approach is inserting this view to the table view as a subview and then adding constraints to it with respect to the center cell as you scroll and the center cell is changed. But I've been having some issues with the constraints (sometime's breaking) probably due to the fact that I am adding subviews to the table.

I would appreciate any other possible solutions to this or guidance, thanks!

What I am trying to accomplish is something similar to the Instagram's video discovery table

Comment: You could do this by using the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method and constantly finding the coordinates of the cell in the center and updating the frame of your floating view to match those coordinates.  Seems like it could be jumpy, but it's a bit hard to envision what exactly you are trying to do and how it's supposed to look...

Comment: I know how to get the center cell, indexAtPoint(tableView.center) will give me the location of the center cell, my problem is the design of whatever is left

Comment: The question is on scrolling where will be the view, is it centre to the tableView/Screen or lets say I am showing 5 cells, If I scroll to the sixth you want the 3rd cell to show your view.

Comment: the view will be right above the 3rd cell at all times (even while scrolling) until you scroll past the point the 3rd cell is no longer in the middle then the view will be right above the 4th cell at all times, etc. I hope this is clearer :)